# Using Different regex patterns together in php

Tags: php, regex

I have three different pattern for match the `soundcloud` , `spotify` and `mixcloud` audio URLs. I know how use theme one by one in `preg_match_all` php function. but i want using all three patterns one time in `preg_match_all` php function. How can do this?

**Soundcloud Pattern**

```
$soundcloud_pattern = "/((http:\/\/(soundcloud\.com\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/sets\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/groups\/.*|snd\.sc\/.*))|(https:\/\/(soundcloud\.com\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/sets\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/groups\/.*)))/i";
```

**Spotify Pattern**

```
 $spotify_pattern    = "/((http:\/\/(open\.spotify\.com\/.*|spoti\.fi\/.*|play\.spotify\.com\/.*))|(https:\/\/(open\.spotify\.com\/.*|play\.spotify\.com\/.*)))/i";
```

**Mixcloud Pattern**

```
$mixcloud_pattern   = "/http:\/\/(www\.mixcloud\.com\/.*\/.*\/)/i";
```

Comment: Use groups and OR. `(pattern1)|(pattern2)|(pattern3)`

Comment: ... and more info here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: i used this way but say  preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '|'

Comment: That is because you placed that after the ending `/` in your pattern. If you can't solve it, **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33825983/edit)** your question and show what you've tried

Comment: @Mariano Now work with me thanks

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary please do not answer questions with comments -- this leads to question abandonment (proven by the status of this page). https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296481/352329 Please help to close this resolved yet incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups with OR.

```
(pattern1)|(pattern2)|(pattern3)
```